# Calling one batch class from other batch class but batch size of both batch class is different

Tags: schedulebatch

I wanted to know whether this is possible.

I have **one after insert** trigger and 2 **batch classes**.
I want to call the 1st batch class from my trigger by giving batch size as 200 and I want to call my 2nd batch class from my first batch class by giving batch size as one.

Thanks

---

Answer (score 1):

Chaining of another batch class can only be done from `finish` method of a batch class. So technically another batch class will only get called when the parent batch class in finished.

So **yes** whatever you want is theoretically achievable.

Also make sure to check the limits of batch class, as there can be only 5 concurrent instances of batch class at a time, and rest all will start to go to Flex Queue.

If you can explain your use case, we can suggest if you should go with Batch chaining or Queueable chaining.